# "No such column" error on Apex page

Tags: apex, soql

I am receiving an error when trying to compile a SOQL query in an Apex trigger:

```
SELECT HubSpot_Inc__HubSpot_Intelligence__c
     ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
No such column 'HubSpot_Inc__HubSpot_Intelligence__c' on entity 'Contact'. 
If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' 
after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call 
for the appropriate names.
```

I've checked the usual suspects: FLS is set appropriately for the field, the correct permissions have been assigned in a Permission Set, ... I can even query the field using Workbench. Does anybody have any idea what might be going on here? The field `HubSpot_Inc__HubSpot_Intelligence__c` was added to the Lead and Contact objects by a managed package from HubSpot.

Thanks!

Comment: I see double underscore Inc__HubSpot are you sure this how the api name is and not a typo? Does your org have a namespace, if it does try querying using namespace_field__c

Comment: So you can run the query in Dev Workbench and in execute anonymous, but it won't compile in the trigger?

Comment: @Rao - that is how the namespace is defined. I tried with and without the namespace to no avail.

Comment: @DavidCheng - yes - it runs in both the Dev Console query editor and workbench, however does not compile in my trigger. I did not try executing the code in the Anonymous code window though - will do when I get a chance